# this.view() Is this Kendo or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am learning Kendo and going through a tutorial I came across this code:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {

},
change: function() {
    var tweets = this.view();
    $.each(tweets, function() {
        $("#twitter").append("<li>" + this + "</li>");
    });
}
});
```

I have been trying to find out a definition for the view() method, but I can't even find if it is jQuery or a Kendo specific thing.  I can extrapolate the meaning from how it used, but I try to understand everything I am studying, so would love to read some actual docs.  Anyone know?

Comment: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-view

Comment: As a general hint: You're defining callback functions for an object here. By common convention, `this` refers to *that* object inside them (Technically, JavaScript allows `this` to refer to anything in a function, but in practice JS library designers will let it refer to the *sensible* thing - the `DataSource` object in your case. That's what your reasoning could have been to extrapolate from code. JS debuggers help as well, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a kendo datasource function **[datasource#view](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-view)**

> Returns the data items which correspond to the current page, filter, sort and group configuration.
>   To ensure that data is available this method should be used within the change event handler or the fetch method.
>
> Returns
>   kendo.data.ObservableArray the data items. Returns groups if the data items are grouped (via the group option or the group method).